# Find $a$ such that $\lim \limits_{x \to 1 } {{\frac{x^2+(3-a)x+3a}{(x-1)}}}= 7$

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I have this limit equation below:

$$ \lim \limits_{x \to 1 } {{\frac{x^2+(3-a)x+3a}{(x-1)}}}= 7 $$

One needs to determine the value of $a$ (where $a$ is a real number) such that as $x$ approaches $1$, the limit becomes the value $7$.

My question is how to approach this.
I wondering if there is a algebraic computation approach to this, or is it more of trying to figure out values of $a$ such that the top factors in factors that would cancel out the bottom denominator and we get a linear term such that we get the value of $7$ in the end.

Just curious to know if there is more than one way to do this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the limit is finite, and the denominator tends to zero, the numerator must also tend to zero as $x \to 1$. This means that 
$$
1^2+(3-a) \cdot 1 + 3a = 0 \Leftrightarrow a= - 2
$$

This means that this can only work if $a=-2$. Now we must check that it actually works...

$$
\lim_{x \to 1} \dfrac{x^2+5x-6}{x-1} = \lim_{x\to 1} \dfrac{(x-1)(x+6)}{x-1} = \lim_{x\to 1} (x+6)=7.
$$

Comment: OK, so i see that you are using the idea of it being an indeterminant form of the form 0/0. Such that this would be a removable discontinuity. SO i guess this is how you are looking at it.

Comment: Yes, if the numerator does not tend to zero, the limit would not be finite.

Comment: OK, so that is the principle i need to understand then. BUT i have another question similar to this one, where the limit goes to infinity. What would the principle be for numerator and denominator then?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Use that $$\frac{x^2+(3-a)x+3a}{x-1}=-a+x+4+\frac{2(a+2)}{x-1}$$

Comment: I was thinking about doing polynomial division like this, but if i take the limit here as x goes to 1, you can see that the quotient part goes to infinity, so  can't see how to avoid that. If i choose a = -2 to get the 7 value, the quotient becomes 0/0. SO i can;t see how to avoid this odd situation.

Comment: Hm if you take $$a=-2$$ so the quotient is zero,limit means $x$ tends to $1$, but is not equal to $1$.

Comment: OK, so if a = -2, that makes the numerator 0, but in the limiting process the denominator will be a small finite number, so hence that quotient in the limiting process becomes 0/finite number = 0. So i guess that is where you are leading me to.

Comment: This is true, is your problem solved now?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner For a change I liked your solution, the up vote is actually mine. Finally we are not in disagreement.

Answer (score 1):

The following limit becomes infinite due to the denominator. But the RHS says that it is a finite number. It can only happen if the numerator polynomial is having $(x-1)$ as a factor so that the factor would cancel out with the denominator to give a finite number.

So, the numerator is having $(x-1)$ as a factor, using factor theorem on $f(x)=x^2+(3-a)x+3a$, 
$$f(1)=0$$
$$1+(3-a)(1)+3a=0$$
$$2a=-4$$
$$a=-2$$
You can check plugging $a=-2$ in the numerator and solving the limit.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Hi Shehil, this is a great answer, just using pre-calc idea of factor theorem basically as the main tool.

Comment: I am glad you liked it.  Dividing the two polynomials using long division, and plugging the remainder to 0 will give the same result.  Thats one more approach...